# Spring-Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService' defined in file [D:\SpringMVC_20July\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\DeccaSpringMVC\WEB-INF\classes\deccaWeb\DAO\ContactService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Getting the above error while running the app.
All the jars in place.Is there any problem with config files?
Please help. I am new to spring and hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you've got a conflict between two cfg JARs in your CLASSPATH.  See if that's the case and make sure that you keep the one that Spring expects.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatching versions of cglib and ASM.  For example [maven dependendy for cglib 2.2.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib/2.2.2) pulls asm 3.3.1, so this is one combination worth of trying.